# Angular: Directive not re-compiling inside $interval

Tags: angularjs

I have the following scenario:

Inside my controller I have an `$interval` running which gets some data from my server. Base on the value returned I want to apply a css class and do some other logic, so I've created a directive to handle this. The problem is the directive doesnt re-evaluate inside every interval so the css class which is applied at the start, stays applied throughout every `$interval` no matter if other conditions are met. I have created a simple reproduction of my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jw54n/

Here is my code for my app:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("home", function ($interval) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.data = 10;

    $interval(function () {
        vm.data = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }, 1000);
});

app.directive("valueAlerter", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div>{{model}}</div>",
        require: "^ngModel",
        scope: {
            model: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {

            var value = $scope.model;
            var amberValue = 5;
            var redValue = 9;

            elem.addClass("success");

            if (value >= redValue) {
                elem.addClass("danger");
                elem.removeClass("success");
            } else if (value >= amberValue) {
                elem.addClass("warning");
                elem.removeClass("success");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *watch* model changes and then apply css:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.model;
},function(value){
    //your conditions related to css
});
```